# Have multiple production environment for multiple customers in NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, express-session

After researching a lot I can't find anything similar to help me solve this problem.

I have a Node server, with several environments (dev, test, demo, prod). This server is deployed in production on a Linux server, via a service.

I need to be able to have several production environments for several different customers.

Example:
I have 2 urls: https://customer1.com and https://customer2.com.
The code of these two clients are identical, only the url changes.

For the server, it must be able to recognize which client is sending it a request, because the data to be sent back to the client is not the same.
The customer1 will have its database on a different url than that of customer2. The server will therefore have to make the distinction in order to return only the data concerning the client making the request.

My question: how to achieve this?
I would like to avoid deploying 1 server per client, which I know would be simpler, but less maintainable.

Currently, I am using Express-Session to define environments.
In fact, I have a middleware which will look in mysql for the environment variables of each client:

```
 con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query(`SELECT * FROM environments WHERE CLIENT_URL = '${req.headers.origin}'`, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        delete result[0].ID;
        for (var prop in result[0]) {
          req.session[prop] = result[0][prop];
        }
        next();
      });
      con.end();
    });
```

It seems to work but it doesn't seem very stable or very reliable to me, am I wrong?

What better can I use to separate the data so that there is no customer1 that can receive the data from customer2?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you using a shared database for all customers? This is not an easy question, there are many ways to do it and it is generally decided by the head developer on the project, or someone with plenty of experience. If the database is shared, then you can just have different customers assigned to your users (in the database) and query and receive information according to that. If every customer has its own database, then you need a separate body to hold the users and differenciate them. Also in this case, keeping all customers databases on one server is not a smart idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Hm... Each client has its own database in order to separate each person's data ... They are only accessible by the server (the usernames and passwords of each database are saved in mysql)

Comment: Okay this sounds good, if you have the mysql set up, I assume the user table has a "customer" property, or users belong do different groups (named after each customer)? On your front end, when a user logs in, make sure to receive and store his "customer" property in the session (coming from mysql). Then when they make a request to the server, you should send that variable (customer) in the body. The server now will know the customer/database it needs to get data from.

Comment: And while this is not a very secure way of doing it (request can be highjacked and potentially people can query data for different customers), it will do the job. If you want to make sure it is done properly, you will need to give access to your server to connect to mysql and get information about the current user. This is bulletproof and if your application is not meant for internal-use (aka it is available online), you must do this.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, and it's the server that queries the databases with the credentials stored in mysql. My logic is to store client related data (= mysql data) in req.session (like client name, database url, database password etc.) and d '' fetch the information in req.session as soon as necessary, make a request to the database with this informations, before sending result back to the client. My concern is a "bug" (my fault or Express-Session bug) which would cause customer1 to receive data from customer2 ... I'm not sure I'm very clear, sorry. Anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a fault in your code above as you suspect. You are querying against SQL only to get the environment, while you should also make a check (again sql query) to confirm that Environment's customer (I suspect you have that as well as the URL which is shown above in your code) is the same as the User's customer. Something like " SELECT * FROM environments WHERE CLIENT_URL = '${req.headers.origin}' AND  CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE yourUserCustomerFromSession "

Comment: Can't further edit my comment, but I would write CLIENT_NAME rather than CUSTOMER_NAME to make it more clear for you (following your CLIENT_URL convention). Hope that makes sense. Before, any user (no matter which client was assigned against them) could query data for any customer as long as they use that client URL. Now this is no longer possible. I will put this as answer and we can continue from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following all comments under your original post, you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM environments WHERE CLIENT_URL = '${req.headers.origin}' AND CUSTOMER_NAME 
LIKE yourUserCustomerFromSession
```

Before, any user could query data for any customer as long as they use the URL for that customer, now this is no longer possible.

Even better way of doing it, if you don't want to hold the Client name in the session, you can do 2 queries - the first one to get the Client name for the logged in User and the second one similar to the code above:

```
SELECT * FROM environments WHERE CLIENT_URL = '${req.headers.origin}' AND 
CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE theClientNameYouJustGotForTheLoggedInUser
```